# ¿Cómo puedo almacenar la ip y el user agente en MySqli?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

PREGUNTA RESUELTA, SI TIENES EL MISMO ERROR QUE YO REVISA LOS COMENTARIOS.

llevo esto de code escrito pero al hacer el form no se almacena ni la ip ni el user agent en la base de datos. Dejo parte del código por aquí. Cabe recalcar que he hecho un condicional que valida con ipqualityscore las ips y así determina si una ip es fraudulenta o no.

ACTUALIZACIÓN: ERRORES DE MYSQLI:

> ERROR DESCRIPTION:Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

ERRORES DE PHP:

> [Sat Oct 09 16:44:00.563492 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 13836:tid 1796]
> [client 127.0.0.1:13544] Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to
> debugging client, waited: 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9003 (through
> xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-( [Sat Oct 09 16:44:01.712865
> 2021] [php7:notice] [pid 13836:tid 1796] [client 127.0.0.1:13544]
> Xdebug: [Step Debug] Time-out connecting to debugging client, waited:
> 200 ms. Tried: localhost:9003 (through
> xdebug.client_host/xdebug.client_port) :-(, referer:
> http://127.0.0.1/pruba1/

Archivo que ejecuta el form

```
 include 'config/data.php'; // Innclude de los datos para acceder a la DB

$ip = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP'] : $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$user_agent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']; 



 if ($result['fraud_score'] >= 50) {
    $_GRABAR_SQL = "INSERT INTO drol VALUES ($user_agent, $ip)";   
mysqli_query($conn, $_GRABAR_SQL);
print 'Get off my website dumbass bot';      // Condicional If para que las ips cuyos valores sean superior a 50 de fraud score se alamcene en la base de datos.
}
```

Archivo config/data.php (Conexión con la base de datos)

```
    <?php

$seckey='1111';  // Here is the admin-access key

$servername = "127.0.0.1";  // Host
$username = "root";  //User
$password = ''; // Password
$dbname = "prueba"; // dbname

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexion Fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
$connp = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);


?>
```

Comment: En tu SQL falta la palabra clave `VALUES`.

Comment: @Sal Voy a revisar y te cuento

Comment: @Sal Una vez agregado sigue pasando lo mismo

Comment: Revisa los mensajes de error de `mysqli_error` y del log de php; agrégalos a la pregunta.

Comment: @sal Listo, revisa de nuevo la pregunta

Comment: @Jheyman Mejia Perdón, no actualicé esa parte en la pregunta, lo hago en un periquete.

Comment: Lo acabo de modificar pero aún sigue dando el mismo error. He cambiado también el tipo de dato de user_agent en la base de datos ( de varchar a text) pero aún así sigue dando eror.

Comment: Si la columnas son VARCHAR las cadenas van entrecomilladas `VALUES('$user_agent','$ip')`

Comment: @Sal He hecho lo que has dicho, pero ahora da otro error. Actualizo de nuevo la pregunta  con el error

Comment: Es porque tienes más columnas en esa tabla que los valores que le estás pasando, en ese caso, intenta con `INSERT INTO table (column1, column2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2')`

Comment: @sal Procedo a marcar la pregunta como resuelta. El problema es que no le estaba asignando un valor a "id". Muchas gracias a ambos por todo :D